Format floating-point numbers with sed to equal precision - add trailing zeros
Is it possible to format floating point numbers with sed to extend to equal precision of e.g. 8 digits after the decimal point?
Because this problem is part of a bigger context, it is essential to use GNU sed
Input Examples:
0
126
99.0234
.38
-47.88
-234.23001101
40565004.22

The goal is to append trailing 0's to each number until the desired precision is reached.
It is sure that no number of the input has more digits after the decimal point as the desired precision. Another (minor) goal is to add a leading zero before the decimal point, if it is missing.
Just the same as bash LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%0.8f" .123 works.
Achieved output is:
0.00000000
126.00000000
99.02340000
0.38000000
-47.88000000
-234.23001101
40565004.22000000

All I found so far is only about limiting the number digits, but not expanding.

An alternative solution would be a way to call the shell command
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%0.8f\n" \3  for a particular match group (here: the third match group) within the sed processing.
Input: <rowNo>|<date time>|<number> (example: 1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|.38, numbers as above)
command (obviously not working, for third match group processing):
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)|\(.*\)|\([0-9\.]*\)/\1|\2|$(LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%.8f\n" \3))/g' test.csv


Updates in reply to some comments:
It is not the point to have exact floating point representations. The numbers in my input have been printed out by a program which is out of my control as (up-to) 8 digit string representations.
I added tag 'bash' because I thought it might be helpful.

For floats, the last nonzero digit to the right of the decimal point must be 5.  99.02340000, 0.38000000, -47.88000000, -234.23001101, and 40565004.22000000 are not representable as floats.

In single quotes, the form $( ) can't work. Is sed "s/^\([0-9]*\)|\(.*\)|\([0-9\.]*\)/\1|\2|$(LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%.8f\n" \3)/g" file what you are expecting?

@Andrew. And that is a necessary, not sufficient condition. 0.15 has no exact representation neither (which is easy to see: if it had, then 0.15×2 would have to. And 0.15×2=0.3 doesn't meet your constraint). But anyway, that is for binary IEEE floating points. That, sure, are somewhere, under the hood, in this question. But fundamentally, OP is more interested into a decimal floating point representation (here, in the form of human readable strings). In which all those number have a representation. Maybe (very probably) those strings will have to be converted into IEEE at some  points

but that is not the concern here (and, strictly speaking, we don't kow. We don't know if all those strings weren't produced by a python script using Decimal, and won't be parsed only by some C program using _Decimal128 — compiled with a compiler that support them). So, for now, those are strings representation of base 10 floating points numbers.

Please post sample input and expected output that's truly representative of your real data. If your real data looks like 1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|.38 then [edit] your example so the sample input also looks like that, not just a block of stand-alone numbers, and add the expected output given that input.

Note that if you want "exclusively sed" solutions (that is no printf, no ${var##thing}, ...) then that question shouldn't be tagged bash. Tag bash doesn't mean "geeky stuff I do in a terminal, preferably in unix". Bash is a language. A scripting one, but a specific one. Running command sed has nothing to do with bash. Sure, bash programmers often use it. And other languages programmers very less so (I have never seen anyone fork/exec a sed process in C to pipe some string into and from it. Which is what we do when we type command | sed | othercommand in bash).

But still, sed is just a program, that we can use from other programs, whatever language they are coded with. So your question is not at all about bash. Even more: you explicitely forbid answer that are related to bash. This is a pure sed question. And tag bash should be removed then

Formatting floating-point numbers with sed. I'm sure you can also clear snow with a frying pan, or eat peas with tweezers. However, I'm convinced that there are much more practical tools for all these things.

@chrslg Thank you for your valueable thoughts I updated the OP and hope it is a bit clearer now.

@chrslg I did not say, nor did I imply, it is sufficient.

@Andrew I did say, nor did I implied that you did :D. I am, on the contrary, quite convinced that someone who makes such a remark is well aware of exactly how it works. And in particular, I was 100% sure that you did know that, since you have already posted very exactly on this matter, and some other on internals of floats. I just thought that the precision (necessary, not sufficient) was need as long as the rule "it has to end by 5" is enunciated (but anyway, my main point was "it doesn't really matter here")

looks like it does not matter, at least not in awk.  I did not expect that.  It's a bit strange, but ok. :-)

er, the float issues DO matter in awk, as I explained below

No answers thus far have address the cvs format, they all assume txt format

@Andrew please read my answer as it does address the pipe-separated input format, which I assume is what you meant by "the cvs format".

FYI, 'LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%0.8f" .123' will not always work due to the way floats work as discussed in the answers here.  For example:  'LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%0.8f" 1234567890111.123'

@Ed Morton OK, I see it now

Those are not floating-point numbers. They are just decimal numerals. Floating-point numbers have an exponent. The exponent says where the decimal point moves to. So the decimal point floats from place to place. That is why it is called floating-point.

it is essential to use GNU sed Is the implication here, that the solution must fit within the limited functionality of GNU sed, must not avail itself of any of the fancy, nonstandard extensions of other seds? :-)

This sed command might be what you are looking for:
sed 's/^\(-\{0,1\}\)[.]/\10./
     /[.]/!s/$/./
     s/$/00000000/
     s/\([.].\{8\}\).*/\1/
' input

If the input lines are in the form of <rowNo>|<date time>|<number>, then
sed 'h
     s/.*|//
     s/^\(-\{0,1\}\)[.]/\10./
     /[.]/!s/$/./
     s/$/00000000/
     s/\([.].\{8\}\).*/\1/
     x
     s/[^|]*$//
     G
     s/\n//
' input


Nice idea to append eight zeros and then cut off after eight characters after the dot.

this is the best one yet, but can you (or someone) explain the 2nd line please; what is "!s"? (seems equivalent to: s/^([^.]*$)/\1./

seems like it means "if no match that, then do this". OK got it. cool

first line better as s/^\(-\{0,1\}\)[.]/\10./ to also convert negative numbers like -.2

@jhnc Correct. I've modified the answer. Thanks.

An alternative for the 2nd solution (GNU sed) is convert fields to lines and using the evaluation flag of the substitution command, run another invocation of sed conditional on the 3rd line (i.e. 3rd field) only. Then revert lines to fields and output the result. e.g. sed 'y/|/\n/;s#.*#echo "&"|sed -E "3{s/\\./0\&/;/\\./!s/$/./;s/$/00000000/;s/(\\..{8}).*/\\1/}"#e;y/\n/|/' file N.B. Care must be taken to escape escaped characters in the internal sed command.

@M.NejatAydin Thanks for your suggestion, this will be the accepted solution. Not sure why, but I also have to delete carriage return characters by adding s/[\r]// at the beginning of your scripts.

See my other comment for why you need s/\r$// (better than s/[\r]//) with the sed solutions. The reason you don't need it with the awk solution is that doing an arithmetic operation on the string automatically removes the trailing \r.

Regarding:

Because this problem is part of a bigger context, it is essential to
use GNU sed

For this problem alone you should not try to use sed and if it's part of a bigger context then you definitely should not use sed. sed is great for a simple s/old/new/ on individual lines but for anything else use awk instead (or perl/ruby/python/etc. if you don't mind tools that aren't mandated to exist by POSIX).
Regarding:

An alternative solution would be a way to call the shell command
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%0.8f\n" \3 for a particular match
group (here: the third match group) within the sed processing.

That would cause sed to spawn a subshell for every number which would be extremely slow and probably have other issues.
Asking for a sed solution given what you've told us so far is similar to asking us to help you shoot yourself in the foot so rather than do that - here's how you can do what you want concisely, robustly, efficiently, easily maintainably and portably using any awk:
$ awk '{printf "%0.8f\n", $0}' file
0.00000000
126.00000000
99.02340000
0.38000000
-47.88000000
-234.23001101
40565004.22000000

I see elsewhere in your question you said the input is actually 3 |-separated fields (another clue that you should use awk instead of sed since awk has specific language constructs to support fields while sed does not) with the number you want to modify stored in the third field, like this:
$ cat file
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|0
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|126
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|99.0234
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|.38
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|-47.88
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|-234.23001101
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|40565004.22

in which case:
$ awk -F'[|]' -v OFS='|' '{$3=sprintf("%0.8f", $3)} 1' file
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|0.00000000
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|126.00000000
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|99.02340000
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|0.38000000
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|-47.88000000
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|-234.23001101
1|2024-02-01 00:27:16|40565004.22000000

By the way, you said that printf "%0.8f" works and here's what that does with a number longer than 8 digits after the decimal point:
$ printf "%0.8f\n" .111111117
0.11111112

Note that the final input digits ...17 are rounded up to ...2 in the output.
If we use input like that with the above awk scripts we get the same output:
$ awk '{printf "%0.8f\n", $0}' <<< .111111117
0.11111112

You would not get the same output from any of the sed scripts posted so far, they'd just truncate to 0.11111111.
You can see more information on rounding numbers in general at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Round-Function.

he asked for sed; hence the down vote

@Andrew I explained in my answer why I'm not giving the OP a sed answer (because sed is the wrong tool for this job and awk is also available to them) and we frequently get people asking for a solution using 1 tool just because they don't know any better and then being happy with a solution using a different tool so I think a downvote for that is unreasonable. Your decision of course.

@Andrew I'm not mixing up 2 and 7. When .111111117 is printed to 8 decimal places by the command that the OP tells us does what they want, bashs printf "%0.8f", on my machine that command rounds up to output .11111112 as I also explained in my answer.

OP wanted to "to append trailing 0's to each number until the desired precision is reached", whereas this method does actual floating-point rounding.  For example 123456789.0233332 results in 123456789.02333321 instead of the expected 123456789.02333320

note also that double floats are precise up to 15 to 17 digits, so there probably is a 15 or 16 decimal digit example that is broken as well (vs the 17 digit one I provided).  Also, the "are rounded up" statement is not accurate, they are rounded to 'ties to even' per the default float rounding.  For example.111111105 & .111111115 both round to odd* (from a decimal perspective, but of course they are actually rounded to even from a binary perspective).  (*Rounding to odd is not the the standard in the engineering/banking/etc. decimal world.)

@EdMorton Thank you for your suggestion, which is indeed worth to be considered. Rounding is not a problem in my case, I tried to express this in the OP by writing "It is sure that no number of the input has more digits after the decimal point as the desired precision." Sorry for the misleading wording of my question

@ZaphodBeeblebrox no problem. Even if you decide not to use it I expect others in future will see the value of using awk -F'[|]' -v OFS='|' '{$3=sprintf("%0.8f", $3)} 1' instead of sed -e 's/^\([^.]*\)$/\1./' -e 's/^\(.*\.\)$/\100000000/' -e 's/^\(.*\..\)$/\10000000/' -e 's/^\(.*\...\)$/\1000000/' -e 's/^\(.*\....\)$/\100000/' -e 's/^\(.*\.....\)$/\10000/' -e 's/^\(.*\......\)$/\1000/' -e 's/^\(.*\.......\)$/\100/' -e 's/^\(.*\........\)$/\10/' or sed 'h; s/.*|//; s/^\(-\{0,1\}\)[.]/\10./; /[.]/!s/$/./; s/$/00000000/; s/\([.].\{8\}\).*/\1/; x; s/[^|]*$//; G; s/\n//' or similar.

@Andrew the "are rounded up" in my answer is referring to what happened to the numbers I show in my answer using bash and awks printf, it's not a general statement of how all rounding works. The link at the end of my answer that explains how rounding works in general and how to get "traditional" rounding with awk if you want it.

@EdMorton ok, but that description implies decimal domain thinking vs binary thinking, but ok

@Andrew yes, you're right about floats only being precise to some number of digits. If that really was an issue for the OP, with awk it'd be trivial to handle the case you show with awk '{split($0,p,/\./); print p[1] gensub(/0/,"",1,sprintf("%0.8f\n","."p[2]))}' or similar (use a temp var and sub() if your awk doesn't have gensub()). The point being, whatever you need to do is clearer/simpler in awk than in sed.

@EdMorton. I agree, sed is not the best here (for me, I'd chose C, everybody's different and apparently the OP prefers sed which is his right).  Also, "ouch"; ya got me--BUT I already conceded the reasons why my answer is not the best here.  :-)

@Andrew That's not my downvote on your answer by the way (in case you wondered). IMO your approach is no worse than any of the other sed answers and at least it's clear what it's doing, looks to me like it'd be portable to all POSIX seds, and would be easy to maintain.

thanks, Ed.  I try to keep things simple and improve as time permits; wrote many scripts over the yrs at Crisco, Juniper Notworks, and AnAss-ta Networks (names changed to protect the innocent) in Support--what to do in the AI world is puzzling (but I do not need to do anything, they need me is how I see it).  Feel free to down vote; my ego is not tied to this site (already got banned for 1 yr. lol).  I think the 1st amendment is back in vogue w/ the huge Trump win!

Probably not the most subtle, but it is pure sed
sed 's/^\([^.]*\)$/\1.00000000/;s/\(\.[0-9]*\)$/\100000000/;s/\(\.........\).*/\1/;s/^\(-*\)\./\10./'

3 commands. The first one add .00000000 if there isn't any .
The second adds 00000000 to ensure we may have too much decimal places, but never too few (it could be simpler without checking for ., but that is slightly defensive : it wouldn't add the 0s if, for some reason, there is no . even after the 1st command)
The third keeps only 8 chars after the ., if there is one

Oh, ok, that makes sense. The .38 part was a good point tho

Yes, I did, after your comment (I said it in a comment, but since it was also a replied to your now deleted other comment ... :D). Is just another sed  to replace leading . by 0. (with a bit more complexity to also treat the case of -.38000000, to be changed to -0.38000000.

I had to add 's/[\r]//g' at the beginning to have your suggestion work fine - thank you +1

@ZaphodBeeblebrox that implies you have DOS line endings and, if so, though it might work for your specific input s/[\r]//g is generally not the best solution as it'd delete both desirable and undesirable \rs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it. Also \r isn't a regexp metachar so there's no need to put it inside a bracket expression, s/\r/ is equivalent to s/[\r]/ in GNU sed and IIRC both forms are undefined behavior in some others.

#!/usr/bin/sed -f

# Add trailing decimal point if absent
/\./!s/$/./
# Add leading zero if no digit before point
/[0-9]\./!s/\./0&/
# Add eight zeroes
s/$/00000000/
# Trim to exactly eight digits after point
s/\(\.[0-9]\{8\}\).*/\1/


-e allows multiple swaps, as follows:
sed -e 's/^\([^.]*\)$/\1./' -e 's/^\(.*\.\)$/\100000000/' -e 's/^\(.*\..\)$/\10000000/' -e 's/^\(.*\...\)$/\1000000/' -e 's/^\(.*\....\)$/\100000/' -e 's/^\(.*\.....\)$/\10000/' -e 's/^\(.*\......\)$/\1000/' -e 's/^\(.*\.......\)$/\100/' -e 's/^\(.*\........\)$/\10/' test.csv


Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the last -e script looks a bit truncated.

I fixed the truncation.

Using ";" vs. "-e",  "$" vs. "\1", and/or appending 8 0's and then truncating 8 chars vs. handling each # of 0's separately might be better.  Refer to the other user's answers.
